# How to remove Eclipse with plugins (on Arch Linux)?

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, archlinux

I've installed Eclipse Java EE (eclipse-jee package from AUR) on Arch Linux. Also I've installed some Eclipse plugins via Eclipse Marketplace. After re-installing Eclipse I fond that all the plugins I've installed before are still displayed in Eclipse Installation Details. Why?

To remove eclipse I used the `pacman -Rns` command, which removes all unneeded dependencies and configuration files. I also removed `~/.eclipse` and `~/.conf/eclipse` folders but plugins still appear in Installation Details. And the trick is they are not *really* installed, but just displayed in Installation Details.

Okay, it's not a big deal to remove them manually but I'm just wondering where do Eclipse store plugins/information about plugins? Because theoretically it can only write to user's home folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following files:

1. [eclipse_location]/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
2. [eclipse_location]/configuration/org.eclipse.update/platform.xml